# MPMoviePlayerController "Loading..." message indicator

Tags: ios

MPMoviePlayerController always show a message ("Loading...") with a `progressIndicator` when i start the movie.

My movie frame is to small and "Loading..." message stands out of the movie frame. I've tried accessing `MPMoviePlayerController` subviews but i can't find the label. Here the code i have tried:

```
- (void)listSubviewsOfView:(UIView *)view 
{
    NSArray *subviews = [view subviews];

    if ([subviews count] == 0) return;

    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {

        NSLog(@"%@", [subview class]);
        [self listSubviewsOfView:subview];
    }
}
```

I only get 5 or 6 subviews, and no one is a UILabel...

Is it possible change or remove this `UILabel`? 
In the following image, my video frame is the black box.

[image: label problem]